# Magento: Difference between _redirectError and _redirect

Tags: error, redirect

I'm using in some Controller Code like:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Did you forget your password?');

$this->_redirect( 'customer/account/forgotpassword' );
```

I don't understand what's the difference between `_redirect` and `_redirectError`. Hope someone can give me a hint.

```
$this->_redirectError( 'customer/account/forgotpassword' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the function in `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action`

```
const PARAM_NAME_ERROR_URL          = 'error_url';
[...]
/**
 * Redirect to error page
 *
 * @param string $defaultUrl
 * @return  Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action
 */
protected function _redirectError($defaultUrl)
{
        $errorUrl = $this->getRequest()->getParam(self::PARAM_NAME_ERROR_URL);
        if (empty($errorUrl)) {
            $errorUrl = $defaultUrl;
        }
        if (!$this->_isUrlInternal($errorUrl)) {
            $errorUrl = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($errorUrl);
        return $this;
}
```

Magento only check if there is an `error_url` parameter in the current request. If there is one it redirect to this URL. If there is no `error_url` parameter it redirect to the default URL, here the function parameter.
On another side the `_redirect()` function make a "simple" redirect to the provided URL.
Note that also have a `_redirectSuccess()` function based on the same logic as `_redirectError()`

Comment: If I use a URL with appended `error_url`-parameter and encoded internal URL the `_redirectError()` invoke should work: http://local.myshop.xyz/module/controller/index/?error_url=http%3A%2F%2Flocal.myshop.xyz%2Fcustomer%2Fcontroller%2Ferror`. Thanks a lot.